# How to make Readonly dateInput for a Shiny mobile app not show up as gray

Tags: shiny, shinyapps

I created a shiny app, with four controls. Two selectinput, one dateinput, one slider. It was simple on a desktop. I had some issues with the mobile app. Basically, using either selectinput or dateinput, caused a strange 'zoom' in, and also brought up the keyboard on the mobile phone. I was able to address this with the selectinput by using selectize = False. For the dateinput, I was able  stop the zoom with tags$meta, and stop the keyboard popping up with tagAppendAttributes, setting the widget to readonly.

The readonly made the dateinput appear gray, which is annoying. I can NOT figure out how to resolve this, and would be grateful for any tips. Here is a relevant snip of my code:

```
# This shiny app will display CSO Snow Model results.

library(shiny)
library(raster)
library(leaflet)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
library(RCurl)
library(htmltools)

#I found that I needed to switch to bootstrappage and div(class()) (as opposed to fluidpage) to achieve
#the control that I wanted over widget widths for the mobile application...
ui = bootstrapPage(
  #The following line I found to be necessary to prevent the 'zooming' that would occur when the user used dateInput.
  tags$head(
    tags$meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no")
  ),
  div(class = "container-fluid",
      h2("MountainSnow App"),
      div(class="row",
          div(class="col-xs-6",
              #note that I found it necessary to use the selectize option to keep the keyboard from popping up on the mobile app.    
              selectInput("domain","Domain:", 
                              choices = c("Chugach/Turnagin (AK)" = "ak", "Tahoe (CA)" = "ca", "Central (CO)" = "co_n", 
                                          "Southwest (CO)" = "co_s", "Mt. Hood (OR)" = "mh", "White Mtns. (NH)" = "nh", 
                                          "Central (OR)" = "or", "Sawtooths (ID)" = "st", "Wasatch (UT)" = "ut", 
                                          "East Slopes North (WA)" = "wa", "Snoqualmie Pass (WA)" = "wa_sq", "Tetons (WY)" = "wy"), selectize = FALSE),
          ),
          div(class="col-xs-6",
                  selectInput("variable","Variable:", 
                              choices = c("Snow depth (meters)" = "snod", "Snow water equivalent (meters)" = "swed"), selectize = FALSE),
          ),
      ),
      div(class="row",
          div(class="col-xs-6",
              #note that I found I needed to use this add attributes approach to prevent the keyboard from popping up
              #for dateInput on the mobile app.
                  tagAppendAttributes(dateInput("date1", "Date:", value = Sys.Date(), max = Sys.Date(), min = "2022-10-01", autoclose = TRUE), readonly="", .cssSelector="input"),
          ),
          div(class="col-xs-6",
                  sliderInput("scaleinput", "Max. value (meters):", 1, 5, 2, 0.1),
          ),
      ),
      div(class="row",
          div(class="col-sm-12",
              leafletOutput(outputId = "map"),
          ),
      ),
  ),
)
```

Basically, using either selectinput or dateinput, caused a strange 'zoom' in, and also brought up the keyboard on the mobile phone. I was able to address this with the selectinput by using selectize = False. For the dateinput, I was able  stop the zoom with tags$meta, and stop the keyboard popping up with tagAppendAttributes, setting the widget to readonly.

So, I just need to remove the gray. The dateinput works perfectly...I just hate the one gray control.

[example showing the gray dateinput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebtkv.jpg)